# Mostar Imagen dependiendo el resultado

Tags: javascript, html, html5, imagen

tengo un código en el que necesito mostrar la IMAGEN correspondiente a un triangulo si es isósceles, equilatero o escaleno 
Codigo actual:

```
 <html>
 <head> 
  <title> Area de un triangulo </title> 
 </head>
 <center> <h1>Determinar el tipo de Triangulo</h1>
 <body bgcolor="#9095FF">
<script language="javascript">

 /* function Area()
    {
        var area, base, altura;
        base = prompt("Coloca la base");
        altura = prompt("Coloca la altura");

        base = parseFloat(base);
        altura = parseFloat(altura);
        area = (base * altura) / 2;


        alert("El area del cuadrado es: " + area.toFixed(2));
    }*/
function tiposTriangulo()

  {
      var ladoA, ladoB, ladoC;


      ladoA = prompt ("Digite Lado A");
      ladoB = prompt ("Digite Lado B");
      ladoC = prompt ("Digite Lado C");

      ladoA = parseFloat(ladoA);
      ladoB = parseFloat(ladoB);
      ladoC = parseFloat(ladoC);

      if(ladoA == ladoB && ladoB == ladoC){

        prompt("El triangulo es equilatero" );
       } 


       else if (ladoA == ladoB || ladoA == ladoC || ladoB == ladoC){
        prompt("El triangulo es isosceles"); 

       } else if(ladoA != ladoB && ladoA != ladoC && ladoB != ladoC){ 
        prompt("El triangulo es escaleno");

       }
     }


  </script>
  <form name="form1">
  <!-- <input type="button" value="Calcular Area de un Triangulo" 
 onclick=Area()>  -->
  <input type="button" value="Determinar Tipo de Triangulo" 
onclick=tiposTriangulo()>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

No puedo hacer que en me muestre imagen pero si el resultado del tipo de triangulo corresponde ingresando valores numéricos.

ayuda por favor 
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es crear una imagen y cambiarle el src dependiendo del tipo de triángulo, como ya tienes la comprobación es muy fácil hacerlo, aquí tienes tu ejemplo con imágenes:

```css
img {width:40%;}
```

```html
 <html>
 <head> 
  <title> Area de un triangulo </title> 
 </head>
 <center> <h1>Determinar el tipo de Triangulo</h1>
 <body bgcolor="#9095FF">
<script language="javascript">

 /* function Area()
    {
        var area, base, altura;
        base = prompt("Coloca la base");
        altura = prompt("Coloca la altura");

        base = parseFloat(base);
        altura = parseFloat(altura);
        area = (base * altura) / 2;


        alert("El area del cuadrado es: " + area.toFixed(2));
    }*/
  
  
function tiposTriangulo()

  {
    var imagen = document.getElementById("imagen");
    
      var ladoA, ladoB, ladoC;


      ladoA = prompt ("Digite Lado A");
      ladoB = prompt ("Digite Lado B");
      ladoC = prompt ("Digite Lado C");

      ladoA = parseFloat(ladoA);
      ladoB = parseFloat(ladoB);
      ladoC = parseFloat(ladoC);

      if(ladoA == ladoB && ladoB == ladoC){

        prompt("El triangulo es equilatero" );
        imagen.src= "https://www.cienciamatematica.com/images/asignaturas/geometria/perimetro/triangulo/t.equilatero.png";
       } 


       else if (ladoA == ladoB || ladoA == ladoC || ladoB == ladoC){
        prompt("El triangulo es isosceles"); 
  imagen.src= "https://www.cienciamatematica.com/images/asignaturas/geometria/perimetro/triangulo/t.isosceles.png";
       } else if(ladoA != ladoB && ladoA != ladoC && ladoB != ladoC){ 
        prompt("El triangulo es escaleno");
  imagen.src= "https://www.cienciamatematica.com/images/asignaturas/geometria/perimetro/triangulo/t.escaleno.png";
       }
     }


  </script>
  <form name="form1">
  <!-- <input type="button" value="Calcular Area de un Triangulo" 
 onclick=Area()>  -->
  <input type="button" value="Determinar Tipo de Triangulo" 
onclick="tiposTriangulo()">
</form>
</center>
   <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/36/36601.png" id="imagen" />
</body>
</html>
```

¿Este código es solo para que practiques o vas a utilizarlo para algo? Porque como lo tienes no es la mejor forma de hacerlo, si solo quieres practicar no hay problema y lo puedes dejar así, pero si no te recomendaría hacerle algunos cambios.